# Непонятная ошибка при создании apk файла с помощью buildozer для приложения kivy

Tags: python, apk, wsl

Я пытаюсь создать файл apk с помощью buildozer для своего приложения kivy, следуя инструкциям из этой статьи https://tproger.ru/translations/snake-android-python-kivy/?ysclid=lgzgatukym550789581. У меня windows, поэтому я использую wsl ubuntu.
Получаю непонятную ошибку, что с этим делать?

```
~$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/anna/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/ecj
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run ['git', 'config', '--get', 'remote.origin.url']
# Cwd /home/anna/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run ['git', 'branch', '-vv']
# Cwd /home/anna/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 56bf7335 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2747 from misl6/release-2023.02.10
# Run ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-q', '--user', 'appdirs', 'colorama>=0.3.3', 'jinja2', 'sh>=1.10, <2.0; sys_platform!="nt"', 'pep517', 'toml', 'packaging']
# Cwd None
```